# Any tool for UI concurrency process in python?

Tags: python, behave

I would like to have a bunch of users log in to a webpage in parallel, do some miscellaneous work, and log out. Is there a good tool anyone may suggest?

I used to use behave BDD to handle the UI automation, but I don't see any way I can have it processed in parallel mode.

Comment: What research have you done? There are numerous load test tools designed for this kind of scenario: are they in some way not suitable for your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Behave framework for your automated testing, and need to run your tests in parallel, or want easy to read HTML test execution reports, I highly recommend checking out the BehaveX library. BehaveX is a wrapper that extends the Behave framework with additional features that can significantly improve the performance of your test suites, like the following ones:

- Parallel test execution for improved performance
- Easy-to-read HTML test execution reports with embedded test metrics (Automation Rate, Pass Rate and Steps Executions|Duration|Reusability)
- Test logs per scenario
- Mute test scenarios in build servers
- Improved dry runs: See the full list of scenarios in an HTML report
- Re-execute failing test scenarios
  Additional information:
- BehaveX is open source and available on GitHub: https://github.com/hrcorval/behavex
- BehaveX is compatible with Behave v1.2.6.
- BehaveX is tested on Windows, macOS, and Linux.